# typescript TS1005: '{' expected

Tags: typescript

I have a ts file with an empty function

**main.ts**

```
function logError(err) {
}
```

I run it with the following command

`tsc -p main.ts`

then I get this error `error TS1005: '{' expected.`

What did I do wrong?

*I have typescript@2.5.3*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because the flag [`-p`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html):

> Compile a project given a valid configuration file. The argument can
>   be a file path to a valid JSON configuration file, or a directory path
>   to a directory containing a tsconfig.json file. See tsconfig.json
>   documentation for more details.

Since you do not have a valid JSON configuration file, the shown error is thrown. Without `-p` it works fine. I guess the `{` represents the opening `{` of the missing JSON file.